# Passing a string between voids

Tags: java, android

I'm new to Java and I'm not sure if I even ask this question right.
I have two voids, in the second one I get my string and I want to use it my main void.
The code is something like that:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 shuffle();
 //Here I want to use the string correctAnswer
}
public void shuffle() {
 String correctAnswer = "whatever";
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to use the String calculated in the second function, why use void?

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String s = shuffle();
    //Use s;
}

public String shuffle() {
    String correctAnswer = "whatever";
    return correctAnswer;
}
```

You could also make correctAnswer an instance variable:

```
private String correctAnswer;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    shuffle();
    //Use instance variable correctAnswer;
}

public void shuffle() {
    correctAnswer = "whatever";
}
```

Comment: I do many other things in my second function also, not only calculate the string correctAnswer.

Comment: @Badr see alternate solution.

Comment: Yes, thank you Sir!!! I answered when you had only one solution. The second solution is perfect for me, it works. Now I have to read about "instance variables" to understand it better :)

Comment: It doesn't necessarily have to be an *instance* variable, it could be any variable that has scope outside that method.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to either `return` the `String` (no longer void method) or assign it to a string that has scope outside the method.

```
private String correctAnswer;
public void shuffle()
{ 
   correctAnswer = "whatever";
}
```

Then you can use it in other methods in your class.

Answer (score 1):

You could either declare a global like -

```
String correctAnswer = "";

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    shuffle();
    //Use it here
}

public void shuffle() {
   correctAnswer = "whatever";
}
```

But remember onCreate() will be called first, so it would be better to return a String with shuffle() like -

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    shuffle();
    System.out.print(shuffle());
 }

public String shuffle() {
   correctAnswer = "whatever";
   return correctAnswer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must return it if you have used that string locally. Change the method type to `String` add return statement `return CorrectAnswer`;

then in your main call this method something like:

`String answer = shuffle();`